# Laravel 5.7. Route model binding validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-validation

I'd like to use sweet Laravel model binding *and* then run some complex validation checks on the model itself.

Something like

`Route::post('/do-something/{something}', 'SomeController@store');`

and

```
$request->validate([
    'something' => [
        new MyFirstVeryComplexRule,
        new MySecondVeryComplexRule,
        new MyThirdVeryComplexRule,
        //...
    ],
]);
```

I assume, that `$value` passed to each rule will be an instance of `App\Something` class.

Is is possible to achieve that?

The closest option I can think of is to pass `id` of a model and then run `App\Some::find($value)` in each rule instance, but this kills the performance and is not scalable.

Answer

> No, this is not possible because of x,y,z, try a,b,c

will also be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom binding in your `RouteServiceProvider` like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('something', function ($value) {
        $instance = Model::find($value) ?? abort(404);

        $validator = Validator::make([
            'something' => $instance,
        ], [
            'something' => [
                new MyFirstVeryComplexRule,
                new MySecondVeryComplexRule,
                new MyThirdVeryComplexRule
            ]
        ]);

        if ($validator->errors()->any()) {
            // perform on error tasks
        }

        return $instance;
    });
}
```

Then the `$value` of each rule will receive the instance of your Model.

For more information, you can take a look at **Customizing The Resolution Logic** under **Route Model Binding**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel's Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic):

> Alternatively, you may override the resolveRouteBinding method on your Eloquent model. This method will receive the value of the URI segment and should return the instance of the class that should be injected into the route:

```php
class YourModel {
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        return $this->where('name', $value)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

---

You can use this just like [@Chin Leung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765615) does:

```php
class YourModel {
    public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        $instance = Model::find($value) ?? abort(404);

        $validator = Validator::make([
            'something' => $instance,
        ], [
            'something' => [
                new MyFirstVeryComplexRule,
                new MySecondVeryComplexRule,
                new MyThirdVeryComplexRule
            ]
        ]);

        if ($validator->errors()->any()) {
            // perform on error tasks
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}
```